# How to update users in TomEE JDBCRealm?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-tomee

I am using JDBCRealm in TomEE 1.7.0 connecting to MySQL with this configuration

```
<Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
          digest="MD5" 
          driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database"
          connectionName="admin"
          connectionPassword="pass"
          userTable="USUARIO"
          userNameCol="USUARIO"
          userCredCol="PASSWORD"
          userRoleTable="USUARIOROL"
          roleNameCol="ROL" />
```

It works fine, but an external application inserts new users into database, so I cannot log in to my application with these new users, unless I restart TomEE but I want to avoid it... What can I do?

Apache Tomcat documentation says

> Because the lookup is done each time that it is required, changes to the database will be immediately reflected in the information used to authenticate new logins.

... but I can't get the changes in database to log in with new users

I'm using form-based authentication with primefaces and JSF

Comment: If logging in in general works, it is not PrimeFaces or JSF related

Answer (score 0):

Did you check you use this realm? Can it be a lockoutrealm side effect? This just does a request so either the db is not well inserting data or you dont use what you think